# How to implement SynthProvider for lldb

Tags: lldb

I am trying to make a data formatter by implement a synthetic provider.

currently there are following method need to be done:

num_children(self)
get_child_index(self, name)
get_child_at_index(self, idx)
update(self)
has_children(self)

But cannot find any document explain those api: when they get called.

Anyone can give me a hint on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a description of how to implement a synthetic child provider:

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html#synthetic-children

There's a fairly simple example of a synthetic child provider which breaks up the elements of a bitfield here:

https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/examples/synthetic/bitfield/

There are also some C++ stdlib providers in the directory above this one.  These are not the ones lldb uses - those are built into lldb (implemented in C++) but they might be useful as other examples.